# TWiki page to Google Sites

Tags: perl, sites, twiki

I've managed to extract the HTML source of a TWiki with its URL and Perl's LWP::Simple module.
What I want to do now is to use that HTML and put into my Google Site as a new page (via a program, NOT manually).

How do i go about doing this using Perl? Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `and put into my Google Site as a new page`. what do you mean? Do you want to let them visited by an google bot?

Comment: @Paulchenkiller ;) You probably don;t use google services much :). He mean: http://sites.google.com/‎ - so probably want move his local TWIKI installation to Google-site-wiki.

Comment: you're right @jm666 :P

Answer (score 1):

This question probably will be closed in his current form.

You should read https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#CreatingContent and ask a specific question, what doesn't works for you.

The basics:

- you should auth yourself with oAuth2 protocol to google (search metacpan for oauth2)
- and send a POST request to specified URL (read the 1st link).

You probably will need too, at least:

- change all URL's in your pages from the TWIKI
- change all IMG SRC links